# How can I create my custom category dropdown in admin side(Create category page)

Tags: magento2, category, adminhtml

How can I create my custom category dropdown in admin side(Create category page) like an image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add the Categories dropdown to the Category Edit pages in admin area, you should create file **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml** in your custom module with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="featured_category_ids" sortOrder="100" formElement="select" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Featured Categories</label>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options"/>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This will add a dropdown to the 'General' section of the form:

[image]

You can find more info about the UI-select component in [Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-secondary-uiselect.html)

Some parts of the coda have been taken from [MagestyApps Payment Fees extension for Magento 2](https://www.magestyapps.com/magento-2-extensions/m2-payment-fees.html)

Comment: thanks for answwer, can you add this for product create page? and how?

Comment: For product create page - all the same. Only use 'product_form.xml' file name instead of 'category_form.xml'. And also change the fieldset name from "general" to  "product-details".

Comment: I need some installData file or note?

Comment: I have empty module

Comment: Do you know how to save value of multiselect?.
After click on save button it doesnt save.